# programmatically generate coupon code does not display on admin

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

I have programmatically generated coupon code, But it does not display on Admin->Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules. Why ?

```
    $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $coupon->setName('testing_name')
   ->setDescription('testing_name')
   ->setFromDate(date('2017-01-01'))
   ->setCouponType(2)
   ->setCouponCode('ASASASASAS')
   ->setUsesPerCoupon(1000)
   ->setUsesPerCustomer(100)
   ->setCustomerGroupIds(array(1)) //an array of customer groupids
   ->setIsActive(1)
   //serialized conditions.  the following examples are empty
   ->setConditionsSerialized('')
   ->setActionsSerialized('')
   ->setStopRulesProcessing(0)
   ->setIsAdvanced(1)
   ->setProductIds('')
   ->setSortOrder(0)
   ->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
   ->setDiscountAmount(100)
   ->setDiscountQty(null)
   ->setDiscountStep('0')
   ->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
   ->setApplyToShipping('0')
   ->setIsRss(0)
   ->setWebsiteIds(array(1));      
    $coupon->save();
```

At last print_r($coupon);  Will give coupon detail But it not displays admin side.

Comment: I have used the same code and its working. Try to use `try catch` when you save coupon to get errors if any.

Comment: I have used Try catch By default. Did you print object After $coupon->save(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG.  Suppose we put exit after $coupon->save();exit; Then it does not display on the admin side. I have removed  $coupon->save();exit;  then it will appear on the admin side. I think this is not possible anyhow. But still thinking.

Comment: May be its because when you put `exit` it will break the code execution will not call any further functions like `_afterSave`. Check `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::_afterSave`